# Getting the values of a char array in a loop pointed by another pointer to the array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

`
    struct mylist_in{
    int enrollment_no;
    string name<10>;
    int age;
    string address<100>;
    mylist_in *next;
    };
    struct mylist_out{
    int res;
    };
    program RECORD{
    version REC_VER{
    mylist_out recdis(mylist_in) = 1;
    } = 1;
    } = 0x31240000;

```
#include "student.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
CLIENT *c1;
char name,address;
c1 = clnt_create(argv[1],RECORD,REC_VER,"tcp");
int n,i,j,k;
printf("Enter the no. of records to store\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
mylist_in data[n+1];
mylist_out *result;
printf("Enter the details.\n");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
printf("Enter space separated enrollment_no, name, age, address.\n");
scanf("%d %s %d %s",&data[i].enrollment_no,&name,&data[i].age,&address);
data[i].name = name;
data[i].address = address;
}
for(j=0;j<n-1;j++)
{
data[j].next = &data[j+1];
}
data[n-1].next = NULL;
if((result = recdis_1(&data[0],c1))==NULL)
{
printf("Error\n");  
return(0);
}   
printf("%d records written to the file\n",result->res);
exit(0);
}

#include "student.h"
#include <stdio.h>

mylist_out*
recdis_1_svc(mylist_in *inp, struct svc_req *rqstp)
{
printf("Start \n");
static mylist_out out;
int k=0;
FILE *f = fopen("record.txt", "w");
if (f == NULL)
{
out.res = -1;
exit(1);
}
out.res = 0;
;
while (inp != NULL)
{
fprintf(f, "RECORD # %d\nenr_no = %d, name = %s, age = %d, address = %s \n",k+1,inp>enrollment_no,inp->name,inp->age,inp->address);
k++;
inp = inp->next;
}
out.res = k;
fclose(f);
return(&out);
```

}

`I have a char array **name** where i store some values in a for loop using the scanf() function in c. There is a **struct** which contains some elements along with a char pointer **data.name**. Now, when i try to store the values of **name** in **data.name** field of different elements of the struct  and after executing the loop, when i try to print the values of **data.name** one by one, all of them give the same value , i.e. , the last value taken in **name**. I guess its because all the data elements point to the **name**  variable and the values override during the scanf() operation. Can someone please help me out to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you share the problemtaic code please?

Comment: .. as that would be handy

Comment: any code to represent your long text?

Comment: Actually, i am using this in RPC operation by creating a client and a server file in c. I will share my code for student.x , client.c and server.c

Comment: @Rahul - Why no code? I think the problem lies in the condensation in the flux capacitor and misalignment of the spacks.

Comment: Remember:We cannot see your screen from here ! So post your code please !

Comment: this is my student.x file :-                                       struct mylist_in{
 int enrollment_no;
 string name<10>;
 int age;
 string address<100>;
 mylist_in *next;
};

struct mylist_out{
 int res;
};

program RECORD{
 version REC_VER{
  mylist_out recdis(mylist_in) = 1;
 } = 1;
} = 0x31240000;

Comment: @Rahul Don't post as comment. Edit your question with this comment.

Comment: Hi welcome to so, please read [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Include code and relevant information in your post, which you may edit.

Comment: @Rahul - Why not try to indent the code. Might be fun but aso make it readable.]

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you are not allocating new memory for each char pointer. are you assigning name to data?
If you can write your code here, it would be easier to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
char name,address;
```

From seeing above line in your code you have not char array of `name` but you have only `char name`.

So it should be

```
char name[100],address[100];
```

Also during scanf not require to pass `&` because array decays to pointer so it should

```
scanf("%d %s %d %s",&data[i].enrollment_no,name,&data[i].age,address);
```

And for copy string use `strcpy` or `strncpy`

like

```
strcpy(data[i].name,name);
strcpy(data[i].address,address);
```

Comment: still the results remain the same. All the data.name and data.address values are pointing to the last name and address values.

Comment: both the cases of strcpy() and strncpy() are giving me segmentation fault.